# Windows cmd won't recognize changed PATH

Tags: windows-10, command-line, environment-variables, path, tesseract-ocr

Few days ago I installed Tesseract OCR by installing Capture2Text via Chocolatey. This proved not to work, and instead of uninstalling Capture2Text I went ahead and deleted the Capture2Text folder from Chocolatey's lib folder. Now, whenever I call Tesseract in a command window, it says:

> Cannot find file at '..\lib\capture2text\tools\Capture2Text\Utils\tesseract\tesseract.exe' (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\capture2text\tools\Capture2Text\Utils\tesseract\tesseract.exe). This usually indicates a missing or moved file.

I have changed the system environment variable, restarted my computer, reinstalled Tesseract via chocolatey and via a standalone installer, none of which has worked for me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. There are *two* PATH variables, User and System. Have you edited both? 2. An error at one point in PATH causes all subsequent items to be invalid. *Carefully* examine both full PATH variables for *any* missing file or typographical error.

Comment: I have edited both. There are no references to "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\capture2text\tools\Capture2Text\Utils\tesseract\tesseract.exe" in both PATH variables, but command prompt keeps looking for Tesseract there anyway